# Getting unexpected error during WSO2 self registration

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

While selecting "proceed to self register", I'm getting Unexpected Error hence unable to proceed with registering. WSO2 version is 4.0.0

[image]

From the logs observe as below

```
TID: [-1234] [accountrecoveryendpoint] [2023-02-10 10:11:38,270] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.endpoint.util.IdentityManagementEndpointUtil} - Exception while retrieving error details from original exception. Original exception: org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.endpoint.util.client.SelfRegistrationMgtClientException: Error while check username validity for user : john Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate for <localhost> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: []
```

Comment: Do you see any errors on the terminal?

Comment: Can you please provide some more details such as API Manager version, error message you see in the carbon log?

Comment: Have you changed the hostname of the deployment?